# CAS with redis cluster

Tags: java, redis, cas

I'm working on CAS using redis as ticket registry. On my local CAS uses redis as ticket rigistry and it's woking fine. Followed installation procedure given [here](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Redis-Ticket-Registry.html)

But I want redis behind load balancer if one redis goes down, CAS may contact other.

**Redis configuration:**

```
cas.ticket.registry.redis.host=localhost
cas.ticket.registry.redis.port=6379
```

---

But here I think redis cluster may not help since CAS connects to 6379 on localhost. As per above configuration if 6379 goes down or localhost (system) goes down CAS may not contact it. If redis cluster runs behind load balancer then one fail other may provide service. How to configure CAS with redis behind load balance?

Comment: That's not a really a CAS problem. What you probably need is to configure the cluster to be available under a single endpoint which will balance the traffic to the available redis nodes.

Comment: @leopal, cas connects to redis on 6379. If it fails, is cas still can contact other redis within cluster. How to achieve this? I'm new to this.

Comment: Your Redis client takes care about this. Also you can usually add multiple IPs to your load balancer and it will remove IPs if errors are encountered but this is LoadBalancer related. Mabye you want to also switch to kubernetes, it comes with loadbalancer and service mesh so it simplicates a lot of those problems.

Comment: Furthermore a cluster aware Redis client will learn the current topology of the redis cluster and stores the IPs (or internal IDs) of different nodes and will route your requests to the node most likely store the keys you try to set/fetch -> there is a way to discover Redis cluster nodes but I never used it.